# Can Autolayout hide a view if it becomes too small?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have three views (A, B, C) arranged horizontally. A has a fixed width, B has a maximum width, C has a minimum width and will fill all remaining space to the width of the screen.

B is an image, which scales preserving its aspect ratio.

On a large screen, B reaches its maximum size and looks great. On a very small screen, B disappears altogether, which is fine. However, in between the two, we sometimes have B appear as a very small image - just a few pixels wide and too small to make out.

How can I say, "if B is less than 20 pixels wide, hide it altogether"?

(I have to support iOS 7, so I'd prefer a solution that doesn't use UIStackView.)

Comment: Can't you just check the width of B and hide the B.hidden = true ?

Comment: I'd rather do it with pure Autolayout constraints, if possible.

Comment: If you want B to disappear on small screen sizes. Then in wCompact and hRegular, change B width to zero.

Comment: @teedyay You can't do it with autolayout constraints only.Either you can work with size classes as suggested by Irfan or You have to check the width and hide the view.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this with some priority for your constraints. Making them break when they are not satisfying the view, and then also have a constraint with width zero with the "lowest priority".

Answer (score 0):

No, Autolayout alone cannot hide a view if its wight is less than a threshold value.
As mentioned in comments, you have to handle such dependencies checking width and then hiding it conditionally.

Comment: Could you expand on this? I don't know where to write the code to check the width.

Answer (score 0):

With autoLayout you should define one layout that will be suitable for all situations, meaning adaptable.
 So there are no "If width is less then.. so do..." , When we have been using strings and sprouts, we would use it, but not today.
For the specific scenario that you are facing, I would set a constraint on "B" that doesn't let it be less then 20. Or make "a" and "c" wider, so "B" will disappear